# Adapter for nongeneric delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

I have a generic class:

```
public class ProviderAdapter<TDto, TModel>
{
    public ProviderAdapter(IQueryable source, Func<TDto, TModel> mapping)
    {
      ... //not important
    }
}
```

and extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TModel> Map<TDto, TModel>(
        this IQueryable<TDto> query, Func<TDto, TModel> mapping)
    {
      var providerAdapter = new ProviderAdapter<TDto, TModel>(query, mapping);
      var result = new QueryableAdapter<TModel>(providerAdapter);
      return result;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create another extension method for non-generic IQueryable:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TModel> Map<TModel>(
        this IQueryable query, Func<dynamic, TModel> mapping)
    {
      //how to create ProviderAdapter instance having 
      //query.ElementType and mapping Func with dynamic?
      var providerAdapter = new ProviderAdapter<type from query.ElementType, TModel>(query, 
      new Func<type from query.ElementType, TModel> using mapping Func<dynamic,TModel>
    }
}
```

Is it possible? I am no sure about 'mapping' parameter type - I was planning to create new Func using reflection that invokes

```
Func<dynamic, TModel>
```

but converts first parameter to query.ElementType. Maybe 'mapping' parameter should be of type

```
Expression<Func<dynamic, TModel>>
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to choose `dynamic` over `object` here?

Comment: @thehennyy when invoking Map extension I want to be able to write: query.Map(x => new Foo() {Name = x.Name}) - x is of type dynamic. It would be impossible if x was of type object. Furthermore, actual type of x (query.ElementType) is only known at runtime.

Comment: What do you need the mapping for? Is it going to be fed into a queryable? In that case you probably need indeed an expression, better a typed one.

Comment: @Vlad Usage from application: query.Map(TestDto x => new TestModel() {Name = x.Name}) - query is of type IQueryable<TestDto>. Now I want to be able to do the same for nongeneric IQueryable using query.ElementType at runtime (query.ElementType is only known at runtime): query.Map(dynamic x => new TestModel() {Name = x.Name}) - query is of Type IQueryable, query.ElementType is DynamicTestDtoKnownAtRuntime

Comment: @JarekMazur are you going to feed ( x=> new TestModel() {Name =x.Name}) at runtime? because if not, then an interface could help instead of doing it `dynamic x`

Comment: @noobed Actual query.ElementType is compiled during runtime based on configuration in database so using interface is out of the question - this type is truly only known at runtime.

Comment: @JarekMazur: The question is, what is `ProviderAdapter` going to do with the mapping. If it's not required to be an Expression (because of being executed on the DB), my answer below would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I'd go for this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions2
{
    public static IQueryable<TModel> Map<TModel>(
        this IQueryable query, Func<dynamic, TModel> mapping)
    {
        var tdto = query.ElementType;
        var typedMapping =
            typeof(QueryableExtensions2).GetMethod(nameof(Wrap))
                                        .MakeGenericMethod(tdto, typeof(TModel))
                                        .Invoke(null, new object[] { mapping });

        var targetType = typeof(ProviderAdapter<,>)
                             .MakeGenericType(tdto, typeof(TModel));
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType,
                                                new object[] { query, typedMapping });
        return (IQueryable<TModel>)instance;
    }

    static public Func<TDto, TModel> Wrap<TDto, TModel>(Func<dynamic, TModel> mapping) =>
        d => mapping(d);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. Thank you :)

Comment: @JarekMazur: Glad that it helped!